# Devo usar input type="submit" ou button type="submit" nos formulários?

Tags: html

Normalmente utilizo `<button type="submit"></button>`, mas vejo na maioria dos formulários o uso do `<input type="submit" />`, existe alguma diferença? Qual é o ideal?

Comment: o uso do elemento `<button>` também se deve ao fato de ser mais fácil de manipular seus estilos.

Comment: aconselho o artigo se souber ler inglês http://css-tricks.com/use-button-element/

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Do ponto de vista funcional não há diferença, ambos irão submeter o formulário da mesma forma. Segundo a [especificação](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-button-element), se atributo `type` estiver ausente da tag `<button>`, o comportamento padrão será de `submit`.

A diferença fica na declaração das tags e na área visual.

A tag [`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) contém um atributo de *valor* `value` que é exibido e geralmente não é fechada ou é auto fechada. Exemplo:

```html
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Note que o `value` do `<input>` que é enviado ao servidor é sempre igual ao texto exibido no botão, acoplando a parte visual com uma implementação que dependa desse valor. Não é uma boa prática, sendo que botões com imagens eram usados como alternativas.

Por outro lado, [`<button>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) tem um conteúdo entre a tag de abertura e fechamento, sendo mais flexível do que a tag tradicional, permitindo, por exemplo, imagens e mais estilos visuais. Exemplo:

```html
<button type="submit" name="myButton" value="foo">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Na [especificação da MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button), o valor `submit` é o padrão para a propriedade `type`. Confesso que não vi a especificação dos demais mantenedores de browsers, portanto minha certeza de que `submit` é o valor padrão se restringe ao universo Mozilla. Anyway +1.

Comment: @Renan [Confirmado na especificação](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-button-element). O *default* é `submit.`

Answer (score 15):

Funcionalmente, com relação ao clique, não existe diferença - supondo um *button* cuja propriedade `type` tem o valor `submit`, que é o padrão. Se o *button* tiver outro valor para a propriedade `type`, ele se torna funcionalmente equivalente ao *input* com type `button`.

A tag *button* foi introduzida no *HTML* para permitir a criação de um controle mais rico visualmente. O *button* suporta conteúdo, o *input* não. Por isso existem mais possibilidades de formatação com o *button*, que acaba sendo mais amigável ao uso de imagens, *cufon* etc.

Referência: pergunta semelhante no SOen - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117639/input-type-submit-vs-button-tag-are-they-interchangeable

Answer (score 14):

- `<button>`: Pode colocar imagens e conteúdo dentro.
- `<input>`: Não pode colocar imagens e conteúdo dentro.

Answer (score 10):

O padrão utilizado pela maioria foi `<input type="submit" />`, devido a ser algo utilizado desde o início dos formulários.

A questão atual é mais relativa à semântica que seu real funcionamento, já que ambas as formas estão corretas e, tirando alguns pequenos bugs em navegadores antigos e não mais utilizados e algumas diferenças na maneira que o valor do botão é passado, são idênticos.

A maior vantagem do `<button></button>` é que ele aceita HTML como valor, oque torna possível a estilização mais criativa com imagens e outros elementos, além de puro CSS.

É importante citar também que botões declarados sem o atributo `type` são considerados como se tivessem `type="submit"`, então é aconselhável sempre utilizar `type="button"` quando não se deseja assumir comportamentos padrão, para utilizar com eventos customizados em JavaScript.

Answer (score 6):

Nenhum está errado, porém input se refere a um elemento de entrada de dados, e um botão de submit, a menos que tenha utilidade o uso do seu atributo `value` não tem como objetivo aguardar a entrada de dados. Por tanto pela lógica o mais correto seria você utilizar um `button` a menos que precise do atributo `value`.

Ferramentas grandes como o Twitter Bootstrap costumam adotar o `button` também, porém é uma questão um pouco conceitual de certa forma.

Answer (score 6):

**Basicamente o que deve ser considerado:**

```
<button type="submit"> -- conteúdo html -- </button>
```

Usando `<button>` lhe dá mais disposição e liberdade sobre o design do botão, por exemplo você pode usar imagens, ícones e outros componentes para renderizar o botão o que é mais comum. Além disso, você pode ainda criar outras tags `<span>`,`<small>` dentro da tag `<button>`, e fazer o que desejar com elas.

```
<input type="submit" />
```

Usanto tag `<input>` é a maneira mais fácil de enviar um formulário. Ele não requer nada além da própria tag, nem mesmo um value.O problema é que este botão é muito feio e simples, você pode até estilizá-lo, mais terá limitações.

Então, prefira `<input>` quando seu formulário é simples e não requer muita estilização e `<button>` quando o contrário.

Answer (score 2):

É importante notar que o valor default do atributo `type` do `button` é `submit`.

Com isso, `button` irá submeter um formulário sempre que:

- `type="submit"`
- `type=""` (vazio)
- `type` não for especificado
- Em suma: `type` tiver qualquer valor que não seja nem `reset` nem `button`

Veja aqui a especificação de [valores possíveis de type para button](http://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-input-type)

Answer (score 2):

O input tem parâmetros que são enviados, por exemplo:

```
<input type="text" name="nome">
<input type="date" name="nasciimento">
<input type="submit" name="OK">
```

O código acima envia os campos:

- nome
- nascimento
- OK

---

```
<input type="text" name="nome">
<input type="date" name="nasciimento">
<button type="submit">OK</button>
```

No codigo acima sera enviado os campos:

- nome
- nascimento

Se for relevante receber o input do OK o ideal é utilizar input, se não é relevante o botão reduz um elemento a ser enviado dentro do formulário, ai vai depender de seu projeto para saber qual seria melhor para se utilizar.