# Como incluir Glyphicon do Bootstrap dentro da tag "<input></input>"?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-glyphicons

Com o seguinte código:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Editar
</a>
```

Eu consigo criar botões como esses:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém não estou conseguindo fazer com `input`:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Salvar">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span>
</input>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Botões do tipo `input`, não permitem código `html`, para isto use:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Salvar">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span>
</button>
```

Veja esta pergunta [Devo usar input type="submit" ou button type="submit" nos formulários?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12285/devo-usar-input-type-submit-ou-button-type-submit-nos-formularios), relacionada a sua dúvida.

Comment: Apesar da outra resposta ser mais completa, esta foi a que melhor me serviu.

Answer (score 10):

### Para obter botões com ícone, mantendo a tag input:

Uma solução bem simples é usar o `label` do submit como pseudo-botão, e esconder o `submit` original:

```html
<label for="salvar" class="btn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></i>Salvar</label>
<input id="salvar" name="salvar" type="submit" value="Salvar" class="hidden">
```

Explicação: Quando você define um `label for=`, o *click* no label é propagado para o input correspondente.

### Para colocar ícones nos campos de texto:

Neste caso, "cercamos" o input com uma `div`, colocando o ícone sobreposto ao input, e adicionando um padding à esquerda do campo:

HTML:

```html
<div class="iconInput">
   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></i>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome do arquivo" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.iconInput { position: relative }
.iconInput input { padding-left: 28px }
.iconInput i { position: absolute; padding: 9px 10px }
```

Importante o `position: relative` na `div` que engloba o ícone, para o `absolute` do ícone funcionar corretamente.

> Veja exemplo no **[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Q37y/)**