# Como incorporar várias classes em uma em CSS?

Tags: css

Uso Bootstrap e ele possui as seguintes classes para tabelas:

- `.table`
- `.table-striped`
- `.table-bordered`
- `.table-hover`
- `.table-condensed`

Na minha aplicação tenho várias tabelas. Para facilitar a manutenção, criei a classe `.tabela` e usei jQuery para adicionar as classes que quero:

```
jQuery.ready(function() {
  $(".tabela")
    .addClass("table table-striped table-bordered");
});
```

Assim eu consigo modificar facilmente todas as tabelas da aplicação editando apenas o trecho acima, caso queira adicionar/remover essas classes do Bootstrap.

Minha dúvida é se não teria um jeito de usar CSS para incorporar essas classes na classe `.tabela`. Acho que isso seria melhor prática do que usar Javascript.

Comment: Não entendo a necessidade de ter várias classes se no fim vais adiciona-las todas na mesma tabela. Adicione tudo na mesma classe e apague o que é comum.

Comment: @Filipe Acontece que essas classes são definidas pelo framework [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) e não por mim. Não sei se seria uma boa ideia editar o código fonte dele.

Comment: Não edite o código fonte, faça um novo css e coloque lá as suas edições, assim você mantém o framework intacto. O que você quer fazer, penso não ser possível com CSS.

Comment: Acredito que a forma como você fez é a melhor maneira (utilizando o JS), sem alterar o css do framework. Não há herança em CSS.

Comment: OK @Filipe, deixarei assim mesmo. Acho que fica mais DRY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR

Em CSS puro não há herança.

## Classes?

Embora usemos o termo "classe" para um tipo de elemento de formatação em CSS, na verdade o termo é uma sobrecarga e não corresponde ao conceito da Programação Orientada a Objetos.

## E agora?

Devido essa limitação do CSS, surgiram algumas "linguagens" alternativas como [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) e [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/).

O Bootstrap, por exemplo, usa o LESS e você pode compilar uma versão própria como descrito na [documentação](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/extend.html).

## Nada é de graça

A desvantagem de criar seu próprio *build* é a necessidade de refazê-lo sempre que quiser atualizar a versão do framework

Tem também a impossibilidade de usar um CDN, que evita você precisar hospedar os arquivos de bibliotecas comuns no seu servidor.

Comment: Você considera má prática fazer o que fiz na pergunta? Por que me parece que usar CSS dá mais trabalho do que usar jQuery simplesmente.

Comment: @Andrey Não é o fim do mundo, já fiz várias coisas assim. Mas também não é o ideal. O usuário poderá notar um delay entre a tabela "crua" e a tabela formatada. Você tem mesmo tantas tabelas que não valha a penas replicar essas classes no seu código? Lembre que se você tiver uma linguagem de *back-end* você pode colocar isso numa variável.

Comment: Hmm... Talvez um helper do Rails fosse uma boa aqui. A verdade é que eu usei o exemplo da tabela mas eu uso isso para criar de forma fácil outros componentes também, como botões na cor certa e a adição de uma figura como nesse caso [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16720/como-incluir-glyphicon-do-bootstrap-dentro-da-tag-input-input). O exemplo da tabela é bem simples de resolver com CSS, mas componentes em que você meche no HTML é bem mais complicado.

Comment: @Andrey Eu não sou muito letrado em `rails`, mas creio que seria interessante você estender a classe helper ou ainda criar uma classe *wrapper* que adicione o comportamento desejado. Na verdade, já existem [algumas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825836/modifying-rails-helpers-to-add-html-classes) [coisas](http://railspikes.com/2008/8/22/how-to-fix-your-rails-helpers) a respeito.

Comment: Fiz uns testes com helpers aqui e descobri que era isso que eu estava procurando. hahaha =) Assim dá pra deixar tudo DRY sem recorrer ao Javascript. Valeu pela força. =)