# Quando usar input type="button" ou input type="submit"

Tags: html

Estou com uma dúvida simples voltada para a parte semântica. O `button` eu posso modificar suas ações usando o **Javascript**. Quando devo usá-lo ou trocá-lo pelo `submit` ?

```
<input type="button"> e <input type="submit">
```

Comment: Não sei se é exatamente duplicada, mais veja se esta questão ajuda [input type="submit" ou button type="submit"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12285/devo-usar-input-type-submit-ou-button-type-submit-nos-formul%C3%A1rios)

Comment: Não vejo como uma duplicata, mas também não ficou clara a pergunta por carecer de contexto. Contexto esse que talvez pudesse classificar a pergunta como duplicata.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Se pergunta a diferença entre `<button type="submit"` e `<button type="button"`

A diferença é que `type="submit"` faz o submit de uma form em que esse botão estiver inserido; enquanto que o `type="button"` não tem nenhuma ação por defeito.

Via JavaScript pode interceptar o evento `submit` no caso de, por exemplo, querer fazer uma validacão dos dados inseridos no formulário. O `type="button"` não faz mais do que ser um botão e acionar eventual código que o JavaScript possa ter para ele.

#### Se pergunta a diferença entre `<input type="submit"` e `<button type="submit"`

Eles são semelhantes mas diferentes. A semântica deve ser o fator de escolha:

> **Input do utilizador**: use input
> **Click num botão**: use button

"Antigamente" quando os browsers eram menos previsiveis e atuavam mais imprevisivelmente (estou a falar sobretudo do IE) o `input type="submit"` era o mais seguro.

A grande vantagem do `button` é que pode ter HTML dentro enquanto que o `input` é auto-fechado e o texto que ele mostra é definido no atributo `value`.

Não esqueça que o button sem `type="button"`, ou seja sem type definido atua como um `type="submit"`, é essa a sua funcionalidade "por defeito".

[Button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button):

- Tipos diferentes: submit, reset, button

[Input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input):

- Tipos diferentes: color, date, datetime, datetime-local, email, month, number, range, search, tel, time, url, week, text, file, hidden, image, month, radio, reset, password e submit

Comment: Adorei o "por defeito".

Comment: E o <button>, quando devo usa-lo?

Comment: @Haxz Se você quiser colocar HTML dentro, como um svg ou um giff de um Loading por exemplo... Ou caso você esteja desenvolvendo pensando em Firefox < 30 e tenha problemas com o `line-height` no `<input>`.

Comment: @Sergio, "é auto-fechado e o texto que ele mostra é definido no atributo value." Na verdade por recomendação deve ser usado da seguinte maneira: `<button type="submit">Save changes</button>`

Comment: Li errado, ops! :)

Comment: Hoje em dia a coisa vai mais além da logística do elemento. Fazer o que se faz com `<button>` usando um `<input>` é muito mais trabalhoso.