# Não consigo remover um item do banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando remover um item do banco de dados, porém não ta removendo.

```
        <form action="removelicita.php" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$licitacao['id']?>">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Remover</button>
        </form>
```

Acima o trecho de código onde chamo a ação de exclusao.
Abaixo o código da exclusão:

```
<?php

require_once("conexao.php");

$id = $_POST["id"];

$query = "delete from insereLicitacao where id = $id";

if(mysqli_query($conexao,$query)){
    header("Location: listalicitacao.php");
    die();
} else {
    echo "Erro ao remover licitação";
}
```

Comment: Dá algum erro ? Ou só mostra "erro ao remover licitação" ?

Comment: Pois é, eis a questão, não dá erro e nem mostra a mensagem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mude o atributo **type** da tag **button** para que o formulário seja submetido

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Remover</button>
```

Referência:

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

Comment: Ja estava comentando isso... isso irá resolver o problema :D

Comment: Opa, bom saber, se puder dar uma lida nesse link https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers para saber como prosseguir após ter sua pergunta respondida ;)

Comment: Muito obrigado!! Vou ler agora

Comment: Por que usar button e não input?

Comment: Existe um discussão a respeito em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12285/devo-usar-input-type-submit-ou-button-type-submit-nos-formul%C3%A1rios