# A tag <button> tem como padrão type=“submit”?

Tags: html

Se eu usar:

```
<button>Enviar</button>
```

é o mesmo que usar a forma abaixo?

```
<button type=“submit”>Enviar</button>
```

Em outras palavras, se uso uma tag `<button>` sem definir o atributo `type`, exite um valor padrão para o `type` definido pelo navegador na hora de renderizar?

Comment: Thiago, observe o comentário do Renan na resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/12289/8063... o type padrão do button é o submit. Porém, só tem efeito de "submit" quando está dentro de um form. Fora do form ele funciona como um botão qualquer.

Comment: Obrigado @Sam, não tinha visto o comentário dele.

Comment: Tranquilo! :D Sua pergunta é mt boa, porque mts ainda não sabem o funcionamento do button, mas já tem respostas que esclarecem a dúvida. Abs!